# Applying a function at the variable x

Tags: haskell

I am unsure how to make a function that evaluates at x given any f(x). So my input will be any function say f(x) and then x how to I write a function so that I can evaluate any function at x. And this will be done in haskell. can someone please help me? Also, I am fairly new to coding so I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `($ x)`, this is a function that takes as parameter a function and returns the function applied to `x`.

Comment: `evalAtX f x = f x`? (This function is named `($)` in the standard library.)

Comment: Or `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`, which takes a function (`a -> b`), and a value `a` and returns the result `b`.

Comment: I have a hunch that your input is not actually a function, but a _string_ that contains an arithmetic expression like `"x+5"`, and that what you want to do is interpreting that string as a function. If that's what you want, it's a much harder problem, since you 'll need to write a parser. If you are unfamiliar with Haskell and coding I would suggest you start from an easier challenge: parsing is not very hard, but it can be overwhelming to a complete beginner.

Answer (score 2):

> So my input will be any function say f(x) and then x how to I write a function so that I can evaluate any function at x.

```
+---------- So my input will be
|+--------- any function, say f
|| +------- and then x...
|| |
|| |    +-- Apply f to x.
|| |    |
vv v    v

\f x -> f x
```

Example:

```
ghci> apply = \f x -> f x
ghci> apply print 33
33
ghci> print 33
33
```

Comment: thank you for your input I see how that works but what if my function f(x) will be something like (x+8)

Comment: @Mario So like `f x = x + 8`? It's the same thing, just `apply f 6` or whatever you want x to be. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: the thing is I don't know what f(x) will be it could be (x+8) or it could be (sqrt( 7*x) +9)^3